# How to make a background image full size

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a background image full size: that doesnt mean that it should cover all page, what I mean is that the image width should be full window size and the height should be auto(the image should rescale and be scrollable if needed). This is what i have tried:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: url("../Images/BG_main.png")no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

but it just covers the full window and cuts of the lower part of the image,
I have also tried this:

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background: url("../Images/BG_main.png")no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

but then the background disappears if body is empty.
As I am new to HTML and css, I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: for your reference: [https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/jUr9E/](https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/jUr9E/)

Comment: This is easily possible with <img> tag with width:100%. You have any technical issues in trying it?

Comment: Yes, i have achiaved this with img tag, but I want other elements to be on top. And I am not shoure if its right to put relative position on all other elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the HTML to a height of 100% too, like this:

```css
body, html {height: 100%;}
body {
  background: red url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGlzr.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Too see what goes wrong, right-click and select 'inspect element'. Then try to find the HTML and the BODY element. Look for their heights and see if they equal the window height.

https://jsfiddle.net/n6ef81qj/

Comment: Thanks for attempts, but it still cuts the lowwer part of the image.

Comment: Are you sure the dot before body needs to be there?

Comment: Sorry, misswritten.

Comment: I suppose it is working now (see the added working examples)... am I correct?

Comment: Yes, that does the trick. If the body has enough content to cover the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set height 100% to .body class to cover the full page. and remove center center fixed properties.

```
  body{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url("../Images/BG_main.png")no-repeat;
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for attempts, but it still cuts the lowwer part of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (along with your css):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='myBackground.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
```

Comment: Do i put this in body css?

Comment: It didnt effect the background, but thanks for the attempt.